# Pandas: How to add new index levels by column values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to ease some data evaluation on the following dataframe:

```
                                           3                     9
measurement_location voltage
NaN                  NaN      Gleichrichtung    ...  Gegenrichtung
                     NaN               > 50mm   ...  1mm < x < 5mm
B-Säule              9,5 V                 52   ...             41
                     13 V                  47   ...             55
                     15,5 V                61   ...             65
Scheibenmitte        9,5 V                 49   ...             60
                     13 V                  60   ...             57
                     15,5 V                69   ...             66
A-Säule              9,5 V                 46   ...             49
                     13 V                  50   ...             48
                     15,5 V                58   ...             58
```

The dataframe has been read from an excel sheet which contains a table which has indexes on the first two columns and first two rows. Actually its a 2-dimensional MultiIndex dataframe.
The actual data starts in the 3rd row and 3rd column.

In the first two columns `measurement_location` and `voltage` are indexes.

In the first two rows there are **values** of the column based indexes. I want to transform the table into a flat list of values - including the new indexes based on the values of row 1 and 2.

**target**:

```
measurement_location voltage    direction       distance        value
B-Säule              9,5 V      Gleichrichtung  > 50mm          52    # col "3", 1st data row
                                Gegenrichtung   1mm < x < 5mm   41    # col "9", 1st data row
...
Scheibenmitte        9,5 V      Gleichrichtung  > 50mm          49    # column "3", 4th data row
                                Gegenrichtung   1mm < x < 5mm   60    # column "9", 4th data row
...
```

So this means it want to create new indexes from the **values** of

- row 0 calling it "direction"
- row 1 calling it "distance".

I figured out to add a new index for one line, but i couldn't find a way, how to add it back to the MultiIndex...

```
# get line of measurements
measurements = idf.iloc[2]
# get new "index" by values of each values column information
column_values = idf.iloc[0]
pd.DataFrame(measurements).set_index(column_values).unstack()

# yields:
                (nan, nan)
B-Säule  9,5 V  Gleichrichtung     52
                Gleichrichtung     53
                Gleichrichtung     54
                Gleichrichtung     50
                Gleichrichtung     55
                Gleichrichtung     56
                Gegenrichtung      41
                Gegenrichtung      42
                Gegenrichtung      43
dtype: object
```

**Update**: Some minimal example to play with some data:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        ['9', '13', '16']
    ],
    names=['measurement_location', 'voltage']
)

data = np.arange(36).reshape(9, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, idx)


                               0   1   2   3
measurement_location voltage
A                    9         0   1   2   3
                     13        4   5   6   7
                     16        8   9  10  11
B                    9        12  13  14  15
                     13       16  17  18  19
                     16       20  21  22  23
C                    9        24  25  26  27
                     13       28  29  30  31
                     16       32  33  34  35
```

In this minimal example the values of each column share the same index tuple (like in the real data above, column "3": (`Gleichrichtung`, `> 50mm`)).

So for each value i need to extract the index tuple of it's column and assign it back to the existing MultiIndex.

Like described in **target**, finally i want to have one row per value

```
measurement_location voltage    direction       distance        value
B-Säule              9,5 V      Gleichrichtung  > 50mm          52
```

**I would like to avoid a for loop and use pandas methods.**

Comment: Could you post example data in a more easily reproducible format? Between all the space characters and `...` truncation, it's difficult to reproduce the input data.

Comment: are `Gleichrichtung` & `Gegenrichtung` names of columns in the first dataset ?  If so, this would mean that `measurement_location` & `voltage` are indexes ?

Comment: `Gleichrichtung` & `Gegenrichtung` are the two (categorial) values which i want to use to create a new index level. `measurement_location` & `voltage` are indexes (a MultiIndex)

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler: I added some minimal example data (due to my lack of pandas knwoledge i dont know how to reproduce the original structure with its two additional rows containing the NaN index values)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a solution:

```
                                           3                     9
measurement_location voltage
NaN                  NaN      Gleichrichtung    ...  Gegenrichtung
                     NaN               > 50mm   ...  1mm < x < 5mm
B-Säule              9,5 V                 52   ...             41
                     13 V                  47   ...             55
                     15,5 V                61   ...             65
Scheibenmitte        9,5 V                 49   ...             60
                     13 V                  60   ...             57
                     15,5 V                69   ...             66
A-Säule              9,5 V                 46   ...             49
                     13 V                  50   ...             48
                     15,5 V                58   ...             58
```

`idf` is the upper dataframe:

```
# indexed dataframe
idf = tempdf.set_index([0, 1], ['measurement_location', 'voltage'])
# create a new multi index from the first two rows
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idf.iloc[0].values, idf.iloc[1].values])
# map it to the column indexes
idxdf = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(3, 12), index=midx)

                                0
Gleichrichtung  > 50mm          3
                > 50mm          4
                > 50mm          5
                1mm < x < 5mm   6
                1mm < x < 5mm   7
                1mm < x < 5mm   8
Gegenrichtung   1mm < x < 5mm   9
                1mm < x < 5mm  10
                1mm < x < 5mm  11

# mapping column index to multi index
c2mi = dict(zip(idxdf.values.flat, idxdf.index.to_list()))
# create a series by using the columns values as a helper index for the reassignment
# of column index to the new multi index
new_df = idf[2:].stack().to_frame()
# assign the direction and distance to intermediate columns
# by mapping the respective element of the helper index (level 2)
# to it's direction/distance value
# new_df.index.map -> index -> values of the correspnding series
new_df['direction'] = new_df.index.map(lambda idx: c2mi[idx[2]][0]).to_series().values
new_df['distance'] = new_df.index.map(lambda idx: c2mi[idx[2]][1]).to_series().values
# drop the helper index
new_df.index = new_df.index.droplevel(2)
# rename the original index
new_df.index.set_names(['measurement_location', 'voltage'], inplace=True)
# set the new index levels
new_df = new_df.set_index(['direction', 'distance'], append=True)
```

I am sure this could be done cleaner. I just wanted to post it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        ['B-Säule', 'Scheibenmitte', 'A-Säule'],
        ['9.5 V', '13 V', '15.5 V']
    ],
    names=['measurement_location', 'voltage']
)

data = np.arange(18).reshape(9, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, idx, columns = [3, 9])
```

We have as input data:

```
df
                                   3    9
measurement_location    voltage     
B-Säule                 9.5 V      0    1
                        13 V       2    3
                        15.5 V     4    5
Scheibenmitte           9.5 V      6    7
                        13 V       8    9
                        15.5 V     10   11
A-Säule                 9.5 V      12   13
                        13 V       14   15
                        15.5 V     16   17
```

First, clean up the data a bit:

```
# Rename columns
df.rename({3: 'Gleichrichtung', 9: 'Gegenrichtung'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Remove nan rows (if present)
df.reindex(df.index.dropna(), inplace=True)
```

Now, `merge` and `stack` these 2 columns to give us the pattern that you wanted in the `values` column:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df["Gleichrichtung"], df["Gegenrichtung"]], axis=1).stack().to_frame('value')
df_new.index.set_names('direction', level=2, inplace=True)   # Rename index
```

Finally, add in the `distance` column:

```
seq = cycle(["> 50mm", "1mm < x < 5mm"])
df_new['distance'] = [next(seq) for count in range(df_new.shape[0])]
```

Then we have:

```
df_new

                                                value   distance
measurement_location    voltage direction       
B-Säule                 9.5 V   Gleichrichtung  0       > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   1       1mm < x < 5mm
                        13 V    Gleichrichtung  2       > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   3       1mm < x < 5mm
                        15.5 V  Gleichrichtung  4       > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   5       1mm < x < 5mm
Scheibenmitte           9.5 V   Gleichrichtung  6       > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   7       1mm < x < 5mm
                        13 V    Gleichrichtung  8       > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   9       1mm < x < 5mm
                        15.5 V  Gleichrichtung  10      > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   11      1mm < x < 5mm
A-Säule                 9.5 V   Gleichrichtung  12      > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   13      1mm < x < 5mm
                        13 V    Gleichrichtung  14      > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   15      1mm < x < 5mm
                        15.5 V  Gleichrichtung  16      > 50mm
                                Gegenrichtung   17      1mm < x < 5mm
```

Comment: In the first two rows of each column (they have the index (NaN, NaN) and (NaN)) each column has two indexes (direction and distance), so distance is not a "value". Is it possible to take the first two rows as a MultiIndex and apply it to the stacked dataframe by the original column index?

Comment: @maggie Yes I forgot to include that; I've edited my answer now. I would probably just remove that row using `df.reindex(df.index.dropna(), inplace=True)`, then hopefully everything else still works fine.

Comment: I thought of something like that: `midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0].values, df.iloc[1].values])` and map it like `pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3, 12), index=midx)`. Because the rename part will actually not be "correct" as each column contains two levels of the new index.

Comment: @maggie That could possibly work, yes. If you could work in the `nan` values into your minimal example in the original post then I'll take a look at it